# Why does this makefile recipe always run?

Tags: makefile

My Makefile downloads a number of third-party files if they are not locally available.

```
CLOSURE_VERSION=20161024
CLOSURE_BASE_URL="http://dl.google.com/closure-compiler"

build/bin/closure-compiler.jar: build/src/hashes/closure-compiler-${CLOSURE_VERSION}.tar.gz.sha256
    download-if-sha-matches <$< >$@.tar.gz \
        ${CLOSURE_BASE_URL}/compiler-${CLOSURE_VERSION}.tar.gz
    tar -zxf $@.tar.gz closure-compiler-v${CLOSURE_VERSION}.jar
    mv closure-compiler-v${CLOSURE_VERSION}.jar $@
    rm $@.tar.gz
```

Here, `build/src/hashes/closure-compiler-${CLOSURE_VERSION}.tar.gz.sha256` is the saved hash of the version of the file which we already know is correct.

`download-if-sha-matches <hash >outfile url` downloads the `url` and compares its hash to stdin, failing if they don't match.

This recipe works except that it always runs, even if `build/bin/closure-compiler.jar` already exists. Naturally, its timestamp is later than that of `$<` so I would expect this to not execute the recipe the second time I run make.

What have I gotten wrong?

Comment: Do `make -d` and see what causes the target to be updated.

Comment: `Prerequisite 'build/src/hashes/closure-compiler-20161024.tar.gz.sha256' is newer than target 'build/bin/closure-compiler.jar'` which is silly

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `tar -x` preserves the timestamps of the contained files.

Add this to the recipe.

```
touch $@
```